# Migrating ADT projects with different Git to Android Studio with

Tags: android, eclipse, git, github

I have an Android Project that makes use of a library project, but both are hosted at different Git repos as below. I had added the lib project as a dependency to App project in ADT.

```
GitHub.com\username\MyAndroidAppProject
GitHub.com\username\libMyLibrary
```

I have migrated the `MyAndoridAppProject` to Android Studio with the same repo. How can I convert the `libMyLibrary` project and reference it this project? Currently I have copied the entire code from the lib and added as a module. The problem here is now the lib code is part of the app project's repository.

Below is the current project structure and this corresponds to the github repo of my `MyAndroidAppProject`.

```
MyAndroidAppProject
-app
-libMyLibrary
-libs
-build.gradle
```

Edit: I want to keep the lib project as an independent Git project as it is used by other apps as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to keep both projects in git completely independant, right?
In that case, you should:

1 - Create an `ExampleApp` with the `libMyLibrary` on it (and keep it in its own repository).

2 - Make `MyAndroidAppProject` to have an external reference to that library, modifying your build.gradle:

```
include ':app', ":libmylibrary"
project(':libmylibrary').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../ExampleApp/libmylibrary').
```

The '`../ExampleApp/libmylibrary`' is obviously the route from `MyAndroidAppProject`to the `libmylibrary`.

This way, from the point of view of Git, MyAndroidAppProject will have a reference to `libmylibrary`, but it won't contain the code itself, and the `libmylibrary` will have its own source and Git repository, and everytime you modify `libmylibrary, you will see the changes on your`MyAndroidAppProject`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a great answer and exactly my requirement. Let me check if this works for me

Comment: Hope that helps. Here you have an explanation with few methods of Gradle which can be useful to retrieve the libmylibrary module: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html

Comment: Had to do some reimports, headbanging and some more google searches. But got it to work finally. Thanks @zapotec